# How to attach aux effects to global output mix?

Tags: android, opensl

How can I attach reverberation and envelopment reverberation effect to global output mix via OpenSL?

Comment: I know it is a very old question, but how is it with today's APIs?

Comment: apparently it's deprecated, but how would one do it using those deprecated APIs?